# Remove normalize.css from webpack/create react app project

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, normalize

I have a project which was created using create-react-app. I have recently noticed unwanted style rules showing up from normalize.css . I have searched the sourcecode for where this is being includd without success. How do I remove normalize.css please? It only appears in one of my create-react-app projects and not the other.